# Prove $m \le\ x \lt\ m+1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Prove that given an arbitrary real $x$ exist an integer that:

$$m \le\ x \lt\ m+1$$

First we prove that given $x$ there exist integers below and above:

If $x \gt\ 0$ we have from archimedian property:

There exists a natural such that $x \lt\ n$ 
Since $x \gt\ 0$ there are integers such:

$$0 \lt\ x \lt\ n , with \space x\gt\ 0$$

If $x \lt\ 0$, implies that $-x \gt\ 0$, again using the archimedian property there exists n such that $-x \lt n$ which implies that $-n \lt\ x$. Since $x \lt 0$, there exist integers such :

$$n \lt\ x \lt 0 , with \space x\lt\ 0$$

If $x=0$, there exists at least two integers, $-1 \space and \space 1$ such that:

$$-1 \lt\ 0 \lt\ 1$$

This concludes the proof of "given $x$ real, there exist integers below and above".

Now the confusing part:

Given x real, let consider the set of the integers less than x. We call this set A.

$$A=\{n\in z\mid n \le\ x\}$$

A is nonempty and bounded above, hence it has Supreme. Let' call this supreme like $$Sup\space A = m$$

Now let's consider the set B such:

$$B=\{n\in z\mid x \lt\ n\}$$

B is not empty and bounded below by $x$, therefore it has Infimum.

Let's suppose that this Infimum is not $m+1$, hence there exists an Infimum $t$ such:

$$t \lt\ m+1$$ which implies that $t-1 \lt\ m$, thus $t-1 \in A$

How do I justify that $m+1 \in B$
and that $t-1$ is the new Supreme of $A$? (I guess so, and therefore we would have a contradiction).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

By the Archimedean property, there exists an integer $> x$.  Let $m$ be the *smallest* such integer.  Then $m - x$ is at most $1$, so
$$
m-1 \leq x < m.
$$

Comment: How do you justify that there is an smallest integer?

Comment: For every integer $k > x$, the interval $[x, k]$ is bounded.  Therefore, so is the intersection of all such intervals.  If $[x, k]$ and $[x, k']$ are two such intervals, with $k' > k$, then their intersection is $[x, k]$ (i.e., excludes $k'$).

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good place to use supremum and infimum, probably, cause for that to work you'd need to know that $\Bbb Z$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$.

But: You have shown that there exists integers $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ with $a<x<b$.
Therefore the set $A:=\{\,n\in\Bbb N_0\mid x<a+n\,\}$ is a nonempty subset of $\Bbb N_0$. Because $\Bbb N_0$ is well-ordered (or by induction, if you prefer), $A$ has a minimal element $c$. Certainly $c\ne 0$ (as $x\not<a+0$), hence $c-1\in\Bbb N_0$ and so we have $x\not<a+(c-1)$ and $x<a+c$. Thus with $m:=a+c-1\in\Bbb Z$, we have 
$$m\le x<m+1$$
as desired

Comment: As far as I know, the Supremum and Infimum concept is not limited to real numbers but every bounded set. Why can´t be used here?